# how to run a js file in command prompt

Tags: javascript, command-prompt

I have to run a JavaScript file as an executable to show a dialog with standard buttons from command prompt.
I am new to command line programming with java script.

Comment: I believe you should use Node.js to do that. I also found ShellJS that could help you http://documentup.com/arturadib/shelljs

Comment: Try phantomjs, it's a headless browser

Comment: For Windows Microsoft gave us JScript  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692435(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Standard Javascript is not something that natively runs in a command line environment. It is designed for use in browsers. However, Node.JS is a framework built to give you this exact feature of running Javascript as a standalone.

It can be downloaded from http://nodejs.org and installed on most platforms.

Once you have it you can invoke your javascript file by running

```
$ node <your file name here>.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run javascript from the command-line. Usually javascript is executed in a browser.
You can, however, use javascript from server-site (or command-line) using Nodejs.

Have a look here on how to achieve this: [NodeJs](http://nodejs.org/)
Or you can use the REPL (Read-Eval-Print-Loop): [Repl](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html)